# How to plot in circle instead of straight line axis in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, polar-coordinates

I have a set of 3 datasets which I want to plot in MATLAB, but the 'x' axis, I want to give in the form of a circle instead of of straight bottom line. Any idea on how to do it?

An example plot:

[image]

The normal command for plotting in MATLAB is `plot(x, data1, x data2, x, data3)`, in that the x axis is taken as the straight line. I want the x axis taken as a circle. Does anyone know the command for it please.

Comment: Do you want a polar plot? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolarPlot.html.  Your link doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

@Alok asks if you want a polar plot.  I tell you that you do want a polar plot !  See the Matlab documentation for the function `polar()` and its relations, such as `cart2pol`. Depending on your exact requirements (I haven't followed your link) you may find it relatively easy or quite difficult to produce exactly the plot you want.

Answer (score 5):

The following is a complete example to show how to map the data from a line axis to a circle.

I show two ways of achieving the goal:

- one where the three data series are overlapping (i.e all mapped to the same range)
- the other option is to draw them superimposed (on different adjacent ranges)

The basic idea: if you have a series `D`, then map the points to a circle where the radius is equal to the values of the data using:

```
theta = linspace(0, 2*pi, N);    %# divide circle by N points (length of data)
r = data;                        %# radius
x = r.*cos(theta);               %# x-coordinate
y = r.*sin(theta);               %# y-coordinate
plot(x, y, '-');
```

#### Option 1

```
%# some random data
K = 3;
N = 30;
data = zeros(K,N);
data(1,:) = 0.2*randn(1,N) + 1;
data(2,:) = 0.2*randn(1,N) + 2;
data(3,:) = 0.2*randn(1,N) + 3;

center = [0 0];                        %# center (shift)
radius = [data data(:,1)];             %# added first to last to create closed loop
radius = normalize(radius',1)'+1;      %# normalize data to [0,1] range

figure, hold on

%# draw outer circle
theta = linspace(5*pi/2, pi/2, 500)';  %# 'angles
r = max(radius(:));                    %# radius
x = r*cos(theta)+center(1);
y = r*sin(theta)+center(2);
plot(x, y, 'k:');

%# draw mid-circles
theta = linspace(5*pi/2, pi/2, 500)';  %# 'angles
num = 5;                               %# number of circles
rr = linspace(0,2,num+2);              %# radiuses
for k=1:num
    r = rr(k+1);
    x = r*cos(theta)+center(1);
    y = r*sin(theta)+center(2);
    plot(x, y, 'k:');
end

%# draw labels
theta = linspace(5*pi/2, pi/2, N+1)';    %# 'angles
theta(end) = [];
r = max(radius(:));
r = r + r*0.2;                           %# shift to outside a bit
x = r*cos(theta)+center(1);
y = r*sin(theta)+center(2);
str = strcat(num2str((1:N)','%d'),{});   %# 'labels
text(x, y, str, 'FontWeight','Bold');

%# draw the actual series
theta = linspace(5*pi/2, pi/2, N+1);
x = bsxfun(@times, radius, cos(theta)+center(1))';
y = bsxfun(@times, radius, sin(theta)+center(2))';
h = zeros(1,K);
clr = hsv(K);
for k=1:K
    h(k) = plot(x(:,k), y(:,k), '.-', 'Color', clr(k,:), 'LineWidth', 2);
end

%# legend and fix axes
legend(h, {'M1' 'M2' 'M3'}, 'location', 'SouthOutside', 'orientation','horizontal')
hold off
axis equal, axis([-1 1 -1 1] * r), axis off
```

[image: option1]

#### Option 2

```
%# some random data
K = 3;
N = 30;
data = zeros(K,N);
data(1,:) = 0.2*randn(1,N) + 1;
data(2,:) = 0.2*randn(1,N) + 2;
data(3,:) = 0.2*randn(1,N) + 3;

center = [0 0];                                %# center (shift)
radius = [data data(:,1)];                     %# added first to last to create closed loop
radius = normalize(radius',1)';                %# normalize data to [0,1] range
radius = bsxfun( @plus, radius, (1:2:2*K)' );  %# 'make serieson seperate ranges by addition

figure, hold on

%# draw outer circle
theta = linspace(5*pi/2, pi/2, 500)';   %# 'angles
r = max(radius(:))+1;                   %# radius
x = r*cos(theta)+center(1);
y = r*sin(theta)+center(2);
plot(x, y, 'k:');

%# draw mid-circles
theta = linspace(5*pi/2, pi/2, 500)';  %# 'angles
r = 1.5;                               %# radius
for k=1:K
    x = r*cos(theta)+center(1);
    y = r*sin(theta)+center(2);
    plot(x, y, 'k:');
    r=r+2;             %# increment radius for next circle
end

%# draw labels
theta = linspace(5*pi/2, pi/2, N+1)';    %# 'angles
theta(end) = [];
r = max(radius(:))+1;
r = r + r*0.2;                           %# shift to outside a bit
x = r*cos(theta)+center(1);
y = r*sin(theta)+center(2);
str = strcat(num2str((1:N)','%d'),{});   %# 'labels
text(x, y, str, 'FontWeight','Bold');

%# draw the actual series
theta = linspace(5*pi/2, pi/2, N+1);
x = bsxfun(@times, radius, cos(theta)+center(1))';
y = bsxfun(@times, radius, sin(theta)+center(2))';
h = zeros(1,K);
clr = hsv(K);
for k=1:K
    h(k) = plot(x(:,k), y(:,k), '.-', 'Color', clr(k,:), 'LineWidth', 2);
end

%# legend and fix axes
legend(h, {'M1' 'M2' 'M3'}, 'location', 'SouthOutside', 'orientation','horizontal')
hold off
axis equal, axis([-1 1 -1 1] * r), axis off
```

[image: option2]

---

I should mention that `normalize()` is a custom function, it simply performs minmax normalization (`(x-min)/(max-min)`) defined as:

```
function newData = normalize(data, type)
    [numInst numDim] = size(data);
    e = ones(numInst, 1);
    minimum = min(data);
    maximum = max(data);
    range = (maximum - minimum);

    if type == 1
        %# minmax normalization: (x-min)/(max-min)   =>   x in [0,1]
        newData = (data - e*minimum) ./ ( e*(range+(range==0)) );
    end

    %# (...)
end
```

Comment: You're kind of reinventing the wheel here...polar() does most of what you want.

Comment: I think my intent was to produce a very similar plot to the one given by the OP. Also even if you use POLAR(), you will still have to figure out how to scale/shift the data correctly since POLAR always maps it to the entire range from the center to the outer circle...

Answer (score 4):

You can find [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/2-and-3d-plots.html) all available MATLAB 2-D and 3-D plot functions.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, if it may be not a proper answer to your question (you already have plenty). I recently found very powerful tool to plot on circle - CIRCOS: http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/circos/
Have a look, figures are really amazing. It's not Matlab-based, but Perl, and it's free. May be you will find it useful.